# 2.3.3, 2.4.x Admin Product Grid Filter/Sort by Quantity?

Tags: magento2, grid, inventory, product-grid, multi-source-inventory

With the move to 2.3.3 and MSI it seems that in the main admin product grid - still a problem up to 2.4.5 etc

- we have acquired a "quantity per source" column, non filterable
- we have acquired a "salable quantity" column, non filterable non sortable
- the "quantity-and-stock-status" field is a boolean
- the "quantity" field has disappered

with that, there is **no way to sort or filter** products by stock quantity levels. It is kind of useful!

I understand that with multiple sources combined in multiple ways in multiple sites it gets complicated but still? Seems rather self defeating if I can't sort or filter by total quantity.

In sub grids like the bundle product picker, the quantity field appears, so why is it not in the main grid? How can we get it back, modifying the "override" by "quantity-and-stock" so both coexist?

Comment: DId you ever get a solution?

Comment: @cd-brian i have been hoping for an extension and testing one, but I also plan to dig into it over the easter weekend. At the moment I cant even have that quantity-and-stock-status in the product grid as it errors, something creates a query without db prefix

Comment: aha, 2.3.3 bug found the fix. Now on to grid stock

Comment: Strangely @cd-brian in the "subgrids" like the one where you pick items for creating a bundle, the traditional quantity field appears and is working.

Comment: @iphigenie are you referring to this bug? https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/16209 and the fix in https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/16209#issuecomment-417867394 ?

Comment: hi @user2965205 thanks for revisiting this - the issue you link to predates MSI and if you look in that column there is a second "Quantity" column that has numbers, then this stock status one they talk about. Post MSI there is only that stock status column. No way to sort or filter by real quantity

Comment: Any update on this? Stuck with the same problem.

Comment: the only thing I found so far is using the Mirasvit Inventory Planner - alas it doesn't integrate its numbers with the normal product grid and can't filter on everything (not sure if its attribute type or attribute scope that's the issue) but it gives you product list with total stocks - and some predictions as a bonus.
Or exporting stock data and playing in excel